# How can I simplify this program to check for teenage age?

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to improve my code. Does anyone have any recommendations to simplify this program that checks to see if a teenage number (13-19) is passed into the methods? Or if there is a better way to structure it. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class TeenNumberChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasTeen(1,1,13));
        System.out.println(isTeen(14));
    }
    public static boolean hasTeen(int a, int b, int c){
        List<Integer> teenValues = Arrays.asList(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19);
        return (teenValues.contains(a)) || (teenValues.contains(b)) || (teenValues.contains(c));
    }
    public static boolean isTeen(int d){
        List<Integer> teenValues = Arrays.asList(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19);
        return (teenValues.contains(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: why not a simple comparison with > and < ?

Comment: Why not just `13 <= age && age <= 19` or equivalent `12 < age && age < 20` where `age` is an `int` value?

Answer (score 6):

What about something like this---just checking a numeric condition instead? This is also much faster (not that it really matters in this exact case, considering how few ages there are to check).

```java
    public static boolean hasTeen(int a, int b, int c){
        return isTeen(a) || isTeen(b) || isTeen(c);
    }

    public static boolean isTeen(int d){
        return d >= 13 && d <= 19;
    }
```

It's good practice to reduce or eliminate code duplication, e.g. by making the result of `hasTeen()` depend on `isTeen()`, so the condition only needs to be written once.

If you'd like `hasTeen()` to accept arbitrarily many arguments, so that e.g. `hasTeen(19)` and `hasTeen(19,1,1,1)` both also work, you could replace the definition of `hasTeen()` with:

```
    public static boolean hasTeen(int... ages) {
        for (int age : ages) {
            if (isTeen(age)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is called the variable argument list (or *varargs*) syntax. In order to shorten the definition of this function, you could look into some so-called "functional programming" syntax, using streams, which are able to more concisely express the idea of iterating over collection of values to check whether a condition (in this case `isTeen()`) is ever true.

Comment: I didn't think of doing it like this, thank you.

Comment: `return IntStream.of(ages).anyMatch(TeenNumberChecker::isTeen);` is the stream-y way to express it.

Answer (score 4):

You're overcomplicating a simple task by introducing lists into it. The following method will do the job:

```
public static boolean isTeen(int n) {
  return n >= 13 && n <= 19;
}
```

Comment: This does make it a lot simpler, thank you.